# Entity Framework 3.5: change constructor of entities class

Tags: entity-framework

The default constructor in a generated Entity Framework Entities file is like this:

```
public ProjectEntities() : base("name=ProjectEntities", "ProjectEntities")
{
    this.OnContextCreated();
}
```

I want to change it to:

```
public ProjectEntities() : base(UtilClass.GetEnvDependantConnectionStringName(), "ProjectEntities")
{
    this.OnContextCreated();
}
```

This is because I want to have a different connection string for all the dev environments and the production environment, and have no chance they are mixed up (which is what my custom method checks).

How do I do that? This code is thrown away every time the designer file is regenerated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We fixed it by calling our entities ProjectEntitiesPrivate, and what was `partial class ProjectEntities` before, is now a non partial `class ProjectEntities : ProjectEntitiesPrivate`, with the constructor I need:

```
public class ProjectEntities: ProjectEntitiesPrivate
{
    public ProjectEntities():base(UtilClass.GetEnvDependantConnectionStringName())
    {

    }

....
```

Comment: Yes, but how will that stop a programmer from mistakenly calling the base constructor?

Comment: You can't, but the name 'private' should be a hint :). Plus I added a comment. Since I also want to be able to call the constructor with the connection string, the solution proposed by James won't work.

Comment: Thanks, I was having the same problem, and I ended up modifying the constructor code in the template file (Model.context.tt), which was pretty easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create another file alongside the auto-created ProjectEntities.Designer.cs, say ProjectEntities.cs.  In that you use partial to extend the functionality of your entities class like this:

```
public partial class ProjectEntities : ObjectContext
{
  partial void OnContextCreated()
  {
    this.Connection.ConnectionString = UtilClass.GetEnvDependantConnectionString();
  }
}
```

The file won't then get changed when you regenerate the .Designer.cs file.  You'll have to fetch the connection string yourself...

Comment: This works, except that when you also use the constructor(string connectionstring), you will always reset your connection string in OnContextCreated. I answered my question, with the solution we ended up using.